# Create Rails model with argument of associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, routes, associations

I have two models, `User` and `PushupReminder`, and a method `create_a_reminder` in my PushupReminder controller (is that the best place to put it?) that I want to have create a new instance of a PushupReminder for a given user when I pass it a user ID. I have the association via the user_id column working correctly in my `PushupReminder` table and I've tested that I can both create reminders & send the reminder email correctly via the Rails console.

Here is a snippet of the model code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pushup_reminders
end

class PushupReminder < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

And the create_a_reminder method:

```
def create_a_reminder(user)
    @user = User.find(user)

    @reminder = PushupReminder.create(:user_id => @user.id, :completed => false, :num_pushups => @user.pushups_per_reminder, :when_sent => Time.now)

    PushupReminderMailer.reminder_email(@user).deliver
end
```

I'm at a loss for how to run that `create_a_reminder` method in my code for a given user (eventually will be in a cron job for all my users). If someone could help me get my thinking on the right track, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: [I've posted a sample Rails app here](https://github.com/kreeger/sample-macho) demonstrating the stuff I'm talking about in my answer. I've also posted a [new commit, complete with comments](https://github.com/kreeger/sample-macho/commit/b1e9296bdf9248e36e977deb1d1d0228dc6092d3) that demonstrates how to handle pushup reminders when they're *also* available in a non-nested fashion.

Paul's on the right track, for sure. You'll want this *create* functionality in two places, the second being important if you want to run this as a cron job.

1. In your `PushupRemindersController`, as a nested resource for a `User`; for the sake of creating pushup reminders via the web.
2. In a rake task, which will be run as a cron job.

Most of the code you need is already provided for you by Rails, and most of it you've already got set in your ActiveRecord associations. For #1, in `routes.rb`, setup [nested routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)...

```
# Creates routes like...
#   /users/<user_id>/pushup_reminders
#   /users/<user_id>/pushup_reminders/new
#   /users/<user_id>/pushup_reminders/<id>
resources :users do
  resources :pushup_reminders
end
```

And your `PushupRemindersController` should look something like...

```
class PushupRemindersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_user

  # Most of this you'll already have.

  def index
    @pushup_reminders = @user.pushup_reminders
    respond_with @pushup_reminders
  end

  # This is the important one.
  def create
    attrs = {
      :completed => false,
      :num_pushups => @user.pushups_per_reminder,
      :when_sent => Time.now
    }
    @pushup_reminder = @user.pushup_reminders.create(attrs)
    respond_with @pushup_reminder
  end

  # This will handle getting the user from the params, thanks to the `before_filter`.
  def get_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end
end
```

Of course, you'll have a `new` action that will present a web form to a user, etc. etc.

For the second use case, the `cron` task, set it up [as a Rake task](http://www.ultrasaurus.com/sarahblog/2009/12/creating-a-custom-rake-task/) in your `lib/tasks` directory of your project. This gives you free reign to setup an action that gets hit whenever you need, via a cron task. You'll have full access to all your Rails models and so forth, just like a controller action. The real trick is this: if you've got crazy custom logic for setting up reminders, move it to an action in the `PushupReminder` model. That way you can fire off a creation method from a rake task, and one from the controller, and you don't have to repeat writing any of your creation logic. Remember, *don't repeat yourself (DRY)!*

One gem I've found quite useful in setting up `cron` tasks is the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever). Write your site-specific cron jobs in Ruby, and get the exact output of what you'd need to paste into a cron tab (and if you're deploying via Capistrano, total hands-off management of cron jobs)!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your attr_accessible to :user instead of :user_id.

```
attr_accessible :user
```

An even better way to do this however would be to do

```
@user.pushup_reminders.create
```

That way the user_id is automatically assigned.

Use nested routes like this:

```
:resources :users do
  :resources :pushup_reminders
end
```

This will give you params[:user_id] & params[:id] so you can find your objects in the db.

If you know your user via sessions, you won't need to nest your routes and can use that to save things instead.

Using restful routes, I would recommend using the create action in the pushup_reminders controller. This would be the most conventional and Restful way to do this kind of object creation.

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id]
  @reminder  = @user.pushup_reminders.create()
end
```

If you need to check whether object creation was successful, try using `.new` and `.save`

Comment: Paul, thanks for the `@user.pushup_reminders.create` code. That's much cleaner than what I was trying to do before. I'm still not sure if the `create_a_reminder` method should go in my pushup_reminders controller, and second, how to call the method in my code. Everytime I try in the console, I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method pushup_reminder`.

Comment: Kyle if you want this in your model. I would do self.pushup_reminders.create()

Comment: Are you saying to put the `create_a_reminder` method in my `PushupReminder` or `User` model?

Comment: That example would be in your User model.

Comment: Mk, but perhaps I wasn't clear in my initial explanation. Users themselves won't create pushup reminders. My application will create reminders on a schedule and email reminder emails to users. Not sure if that changes anything about your multiple code examples, but I want to make sure we're on the same page. I'm so confused :)